# Tagging System Scalability

Tags: mysql, database, tags

I have a tagging system on my website. Trying to figure out whether its better to have a master tag table and another table with references to the master table, or a table with each row containing the text of the tag.

Thoughts on what would scale up better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up isn't your problem, it's efficiency.

It is significantly easier for the server to search for the integer value 42 than the string value "answer", for example. It also takes up less space in storage, especially in the index table. You can then look up or join on the tag name table (I would favour looking it up separately, because then you can use Memcache or similar to store the names for even faster access)

Comment: but would i have to do individual searches on the master table for the tag they add to check whether its already in the table before creating a new row on the master table? that seems like an awful lot of searching, especially as the table grows...

Comment: Select queries vastly outweigh inserts. As a general rule it's okay for inserts to not be quite as optimal as selects.

Comment: so then master table with references to master tag id's it is... thanks.